# Adjust height of iframe with angular application

Tags: iframe, angularjs

I have an iframe pointing to my angular application. I need to resize the height of the iframe based on the height of its contents.

**The iframe and its host are on the same domain, so there are no cross-domain issues.**

I would like to know the height of my angular application when the initial data has been loaded and notify this to the iframe container, so the height can be appropriately set.

I use ng-init to set my angular-applications initial state when the document is first fetched.

`$scope.on("$viewContentLoaded", fn)` seems to happen too early.

Can I plugin a `$(fn);` somewhere without breaking too many best practices? Is there another approach?

Comment: why you say that `$scope.on("$viewContentLoaded", fn)` is happen too early? you alerting content' height and this is too small?

Comment: any solutions on this?